# PhantomJS: event handler that executes AJAX call

Tags: ajax, phantomjs

This is a simple test case for PhantomJS to demonstrate that an event handler that, when invoked, executes an AJAX call, does not work.

I've created a simple test here to try and access some content loaded via AJAX.  It's very possible I've done something wrong, in which case I'd appreciate someone pointing out what that is.  However, if not, I think there is a problem with PhantomJS.

Here's a simple page with a single  that has a change event bound to it.  When the value of the  changes, it loads some content from the server and replaces the content of a specific <p>

The text of the <p id="bar">foo</p> should change to 'bar' after the ajax call is completed and processed.

Can anyone help me out?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX test</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(function(){
            $('#getBar').change(function() {
                $('#bar').load("/test/bar");
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Foo</h1>
    <div>
        <select id="getBar">
            <option value=""></option>
            <option value="go" id="go">Get Bar Text</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <p id="bar">foo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here's the script I use to navigate to this simple page and ATTEMPT to use jQuery to change the value of the  and trigger the change event.
The steps of the script are broken out into an array of 'step' functions:

```
var wp = require("webpage");
var system = require('system');
var util = require('./util-module.js'); // my logging API

var baseUrl = 'http://127.0.0.1:8080';

/* Global error handler for phantom */
phantom.onError = function(msg, trace) {
    var msgStack = ['PHANTOM ERROR: ' + msg];
    if (trace) {
        msgStack.push('TRACE:');
        trace.forEach(function(t) {
            msgStack.push(' -> ' + (t.file || t.sourceURL) + ': ' + t.line);
        });
    }
    util.log.error(msgStack.join('\n'));

    // exit phantom on error
    phantom.exit();
};

/* Inject jQuery into the phantom context */
var injected = phantom.injectJs('./jquery.min.js');
util.log.debug('phantom injected jQuery: ' + injected);

/* Create and initialize the page */
var page = wp.create();

var loadInProgress = false;
page.onLoadStarted = function() {
    loadInProgress = true;
    util.log.debug("page load started: " + page.url);
};

page.onLoadFinished = function() {
    loadInProgress = false;
    util.log.debug("page load finished: " + page.url);

    // inject jquery onto the page
    var injected = page.injectJs('./jquery.min.js');
    util.log.debug('page injected jQuery: ' + injected);
    page.evaluate(function() {
        jQuery.noConflict();
    });
};

page.onResourceRequested = function(request) {
    console.log('Request (#' + request.id + '): ' + JSON.stringify(request));
};

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    console.log('Response (#' + response.id + ', stage "' + response.stage + '"): ' + JSON.stringify(response));
};

/* Redirect all console messages logged on page to debug */
page.onConsoleMessage = function(msg) {
    util.log.debug(msg);
};

var steps = [
    function() {
        util.log.debug('LOAD THE TEST PAGE');
        page.open(baseUrl + "/test/foo");
    },
    function() {
        util.log.debug('CHANGE THE SELECT');
        // see what the first result is.  change the sort.  Wait for the ajax update to complete
        // start iterating over results.
        var oldTitle = page.evaluate(function() {
            return jQuery('#bar').text();
        });
        util.log.debug('OLD TEXT: ' + oldTitle);
        page.evaluate(function(){
            jQuery('select').val('go');
            jQuery('select').trigger('change');
            jQuery('select').change();
            console.log('SELECT VALUE AFTER UDPATE: ' + jQuery('select').val());
        });
        loadInProgress = true;
        count = 0;
        var fint = setInterval(function() {
            var newTitle = page.evaluate(function() {
                return jQuery('#bar').text();
            });
            util.log.debug('NEW TEXT: ' + newTitle);
            count++;
            if (oldTitle != newTitle) {
                clearInterval(fint);
                loadInProgress = false;
            }
            if (count > 5) {
                clearInterval(fint);
                loadInProgress = false;
            }
        }, 500);

    },
    function() {
        util.log.debug('PRINT PAGE TITLE');
        page.evaluate(function(){
            console.log(document.title);
        });
    },

];

// harness that executes each step of the scraper
var testIndex = 0;
interval = setInterval(function() {
    if (!loadInProgress && typeof steps[testIndex] == "function") {
        util.log.debug("step " + (testIndex + 1));
        steps[testIndex]();
        testIndex++;
    }
    if (typeof steps[testIndex] != "function") {
        util.log.debug("test complete!");
        clearInterval(interval);
        phantom.exit();
    }
}, 500);
```

And here is the output.  I'm expecting the text to change from 'foo' to 'bar' but it never happens

```
DEBUG: CHANGE THE SELECT
DEBUG: OLD TEXT: foo
DEBUG: SELECT VALUE AFTER UDPATE: go
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: NEW TEXT: foo
DEBUG: step 5
DEBUG: PRINT PAGE TITLE
DEBUG: AJAX test
DEBUG: test complete!
```

Comment: Instead of checking every 500 ms if the title has changed, better intercept all requests in onResourceRequested (you can add custom header to all ajax requests and check for its persistence)

Answer (score 2):

BTW, PhantomJS 1.7.   This is a great project.

The problem with the example listed above is that I simply injected jQuery into a page that already had jQuery.  When I stopped doing that, it worked.

Comment: resolved in other answer: $jq = window.jQuery; $jq.noConflict(); $jq('body').offset();

Comment: DOH! I make the same mistake, injected jQuery which f*cked up my page... removed the inject, and bam! thanks!